# How do I change the color of my bar plot using ggplot2 package of R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am practicing to create a bar chart using the following data frame and packages -

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

df = data.frame (Bacteria = c("Acinetobacter", 
                          "Citrobacter", 
                          "Enterobacter", 
                          "Eschwerichia coli",
                          "Klebsiella",
                          "Proteus",
                          "Pseudomonas aeruginosa",
                          "Serratia"),
             Count = c(82,32,55,193, 110,58,200,8),
             Percentage = c(11.1, 4.3, 7.5, 26.2, 14.9, 7.9, 27.1, 1.1))

p1 = ggplot (data = df, aes(x = Percentage, y = Bacteria))+ 
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

So, now I want to add some colors to my plot and I tried `RColorBrewer`package.

```
p1++scale_color_brewer(palette="Set3")
```

but no color has changed at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In your question, you inverted `x` and `y` into yout `aes`. Can you correct it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add some filling, you should add a `fill` argument into your `aes`.

Something like that should work:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

ggplot (data = df, aes(y = Percentage, x = Bacteria, fill = Bacteria))+ 
  geom_col()+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set3")
```

[image]

Does this answer your question ?

---

NB: Please note that `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is exactly the same that `geom_col()`